# Enhancing MATLAB Figures's Quality To Be Included In MS Word, MS PowerPoint or PDF Document

Tags: matlab, ms-word

The problem is that when I paste a figure from MATLAB to MS Word, the quality of the figure(font size, line width and overall appearance) is very low in comparison with figures made by other software packages such as MS Excel or SigmaPlot. More specifically, the font size are too small for MS Word document. Lines' width are too narrow. I can fix them by changing the font size and line width but it is just too much work for such an essential things. My scripts produce more than 20 figures each time that I run them and it is not reasonable to modify them one by one manually or through the code. I expect that MATLAB has something ready to deal with this problem(optimizing font size, line width for pasting the figure into MS Word or PDF, etc).

I don't know whether I'm using a bad way to paste the figure into MS Word (Edit>Copy Figure) or it is just the way MATLAB is.

The following is a image from the PDF file including a figure made by MATLAB. See how ugly and small is the figure. The labels and texts in the figure are hardly readable.

[image]

Comment: Save the figure rather than copy and pasting it. If I'm not mistaken you can save it as a PDF in which case it will be a vector graphic and have no resolution issues.

Comment: The problem is not resolution. The problem is font size and line's width is not appropriate i.e. too small/narrow.

Comment: If you can fix this by changing the font size then why don't you do it in code after creating each figure? Otherwise export the data to excel and plot graphs there if you want them to look like microsoft graphs, which you can also automate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of things to say about exporting figures properly.
You can read my answer to a previous question that may point you into the right direction:

[MATLAB only prints a part of my figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341222/matlab-only-prints-a-part-of-my-figure/11391674#11391674)

And if you really produce a lot of figures (20 is not very much) you should rely on doing it programmatically to ensure that the results have the same styles. The trick is that you don't do all the style defines for each plot separately but define cell arrays of styles that you can easily reuse, like so

```
plotstyle = {'MarkerSize',5,'LineWidth',3};
textstyle = {'FontWeight','demi','FontSize',12};

plot(data1,plotstyle{:})
plot(data2,plotstyle{:})
title('Some title',textstyle{:})
```

Answer (score 1):

Export as eps and switch to [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) for best quality (you objectively can't get better than that; eps is a vector based graphics format, ie no change in quality how much you zoom in on the plot). However it is quite the large step from MS word to latex..

You still have to fiddle with font size and such, I don't know any builtin optimisation option for that :/ There are some LaTeX tools that help, but don't expect the tools to do *everything* for you.

**tldr:** If you want uber graphics and document layout: LaTeX+eps

Comment: Thanks but what you said has nothing to do with what I asked for. The problem is not MS Word. The problem is MATLAB makes ugly figures.

Comment: and I suggested using eps figures, which ms word can't handle, hence the latex remark. But you probably want an easier fix..

Comment: @Struyf: I actually saved matlab figure in eps format and then insert it in MS Word. It enhanced the quality a great deal. MS Word can handle eps.

Comment: not completely native, they're processed and filtered ([info](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/graphics-file-types-word-can-use-HP005189346.aspx)). I experimented a bit and it looks like it converts everything to straight lines. Try including some fancy eps file with lots of curves, zoom in and see for yourself.. But we're going a bit off topic here..